# Problems with Spring Cloud Gateway route path

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm making a practice project where I use the Spring Cloud Gateway, Eureka as the service registry and a service called "serviceA" to forward requests to.
I have created 3 maven projects, namely the service-registry, the api gateway and the service A.
This is all done using Docker for containerization and a docker compose .yml file.

(The spring cloud version I'm using is 2021.0.5)

I provide below some useful files.

**application.yml of serviceA**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: serviceA

server:
  port: 0

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://service-registry:8761/eureka/
```

**application.yml of API gateway**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gatewayapi    
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
         
      routes:
      
      - id: serviceA
        uri: lb://serviceA
        predicates:
        - Path=/serviceA/**
    
    
server:
  port: 8080


eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://service-registry:8761/eureka/
```

**application.yml of service registry**

```
server:
  port: 8761

# per evitare di registrare eureka stesso
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
```

**docker compose**

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  gateway-api:
    container_name: gateway-api
    image: ibm-cloud-academy/gateway-api:v1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - back-tier

  service-registry:
    container_name: service-registry
    image: ibm-cloud-academy/service-registry:v1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    networks:
      - back-tier

  serviceA1:
    container_name: serviceA
    image: ibm-cloud-academy/service_a:v1
    restart: always
    networks:
      - back-tier



networks:
  back-tier:
```

**ServiceA Controller**

```
@RestController
public class ServiceAController {
    
    @GetMapping(value="/")
    public String serviceA() {
                
        return "test";
        
    }
}
```

When I try to make a request to service A by typing "http://localhost:8080/serviceA" I get a 404 error instead of the string "test".
Requests are forwarded only if I enter the address "http://localhost:8080/SERVICEA" in the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could try to add the annotation `@RequestMapping` on the  `ServiceAController` to map the class on a specific path.
In your case you could use `@RequestMapping(value="serviceA")` since you have specified `Path=/serviceA/**` in the predicates section of your route.